# How to prevent product create/update in Prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, hook, product

I'm currently developing a module in Prestashop. My scenario is to call an API, and if this API is successful, then proceed with product create/update as normal. However, should the API fail for whatever reason, the product create/update should be prevented in Prestashop.

Is there any way to do this in `hookActionProductUpdate`? Or is there another way or hook to achieve my scenario?

Comment: I think you should use Prestashop webservices for this job, so you can trigger product creation/update based on your API response.

Comment: you don't really need to use webservice, if you want to prevent update/create if API fails, isn't it enough to just check if everything is ok with an API? if not, you stop the process, if everything is ok, you proceed?